# Ruby on Rails связь "многие-ко-многим"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть две таблицы: master и type_service. Для их связи существует таблица master_service:

```
class Master < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :master_services,
           foreign_key: 'master_id',
           dependent: :destroy
    has_many :type_services, :through => :master_services
    has_many :photo_masters
end

class TypeService < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :master_services
    has_many :masters, :through => :master_services
end

class MasterService < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :master
    belongs_to :type_service
end
```

При создании мастера, в параметрах передается массив с type_service_id. Как можно в функции create у мастера создать новые строки в таблице master_service?

Я пытался делать так:

```
def create
  @master = Master.new(master_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @master.save
        @services = master_params[:type_service_ids]
        @services.each do |service|
            if !service.empty?
                @master_service = @master.master_services.build(type_service_id: service)
                @master_service.save
            end
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @master, notice: 'Мастер создан.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @master }
    else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @master.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

В результате при попытке сохранения появляется ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для кусков кода не на JS/HTML/CSS следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).

Comment: какие-нибудь валидации есть?

Comment: Нет, валидаций нет.

Comment: А по-моему, есть, просто вы их не видите :) Перед `@master_service.save` посмотрите на `@master_service.attributes`. Если разгадка не всплывёт, приложите результаты в вопрос.